# Custom validator error text through javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-2.0

I want to set ASP.net custom validator error parameter text through client side javascript. How can access it via sender, args parameters in my function?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230281/how-can-i-rewrite-the-errormessage-for-a-customvalidator-control-on-the-client

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do is define the callback method in the [ClientValidationFunction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.clientvalidationfunction.aspx) property of the CustomValidator definition:

```
<asp:CustomValidator id="CustomValidator1" 
   ...
   ClientValidationFunction="ClientValidationFunction" />
```

You can then define a client side validation script:

```
<script language="javascript">
function ClientValidationFunction(sender, args){

    var valid = false;
    // Validation logic..

    sender.errormessage = "Validation failed";

    args.IsValid = valid;
    return;        
}
</script>
```

Update: The **sender** variable holds a reference to the custom validator control - because JavaScript is dynamically typed, we can just update its `errormessage` property directly:

```
    sender.errormessage = "This is a new validation message";
```

Comment: Thanks Dexter, I want to know how to set the validator's error message parameter throught javascript.

Comment: what is 'source' in your example ?

Comment: Sorry - it should be `sender`

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

```
var clientValidationFunction = function(sender, args) {
    sender.textContent = sender.innerText = sender.innerHTML = "My new error text";
    // etc...
};
```

I just looked at the sender object and replaced all occurrences of the current error string, with the new error string.