# Get error message when using custom validation attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, data-annotations, customvalidator

I'm using the CustomValidationAttribute like this

```
[CustomValidation(typeof(MyValidator),"Validate",ErrorMessage = "Foo")]
```

And my validator contains this code

> ```
> public class MyValidator {
>     public static ValidationResult Validate(TestProperty testProperty, ValidationContext validationContext) {
>         if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(testProperty.Name)) {
>             return new ValidationResult(""); <-- how can I get the error message  from the custom validation attribute? 
>         }
>         return ValidationResult.Success;
>     }
> }
> ```

So how can I get the error message from the custom validation attribute?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no reliable way to get the error message from the attribute. Alternatively you could write a custom validation attribute:

```
[MyValidator(ErrorMessage = "Foo")]
public TestProperty SomeProperty { get; set; }
```

like this:

```
public class MyValidatorAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var testProperty = (TestProperty)value;
        if (testProperty == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(testProperty.Name))
        {
            return new ValidationResult(FormatErrorMessage(validationContext.DisplayName));
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

In this case the error message will be inferred from the custom validation attribute.

Comment: Yes there is a reliable way. For a better answer to the actual question asked please see my answer below.

Answer (score 9):

I know this is a little of an old post, but I will provide an better answer to the question.

The asker wants to use the `CustomValidationAttribute` and pass in an error message using the `ErrorMessage` property.

If you would like your static method to use the error message that you provided when decorating your property, then you return either:

`new ValidationResult(string.Empty)` or `ValidationResult("")` or `ValidationResult(null)`.

The `CustomValidationAttribute` overrides the `FormatErrorMessage` of its base class and does a conditional check for `string.IsNullOrEmpty`.

Comment: Thank you. Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can look into the following posting to get some ideas on how to do what you want to do (they use JS):

[Custom validator error text through javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4012387/custom-validator-error-text-through-javascript?lq=1)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I have found that works is to validate the model from the post back method using TryValidateObject and if it fails, show the model again - then the error will show up.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Standard(Standard model)
    {
        var valContext = new ValidationContext(model, null, null);
        var valResults = new List<ValidationResult>();;
        bool b = Validator.TryValidateObject(model, valContext, valResults, true);
        if(!b)
            return View(model);
        ...
```