# How to use validation dynamically?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, regex, validation-controls

I am using below .aspx code to validate `textbox`..this is working perfectly

```
<asp:TextBox ID="tbnooflecture" runat="server"  Width="113px" Height="33px">
</asp:TextBox>
  <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1"  
       ForeColor="#6600FF" runat="server" 
       ErrorMessage="Total Attendence Should be Like 3 or 50" 
       ValidationGroup="upper" Display="Dynamic" 
       ControlToValidate="tbnooflecture" 
       ValidationExpression="[0-9][0-9]|[0-9]">*
    </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

What I want that above this `textbox` there is `dropdownlist named batchname` and if length of batchname is 2, I want to put validation that Attendence should be even no.

I have used below code on button click

```
 if (lenghth == 2)
 {
    if (!System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(name, "[1-9][02468]"))
    {
        Label5.Text = "Only Even Entry for Labs";
        Label5.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

I want to do it on client-side.  How can I do it in C#?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `custom-validation` control of `asp.net`.

Few useful links

https://web.archive.org/web/20211020145934/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/073102-1.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f5db6z8k%28v=vs.71%29.aspx
http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/control_customvalidator.asp
[Custom validator error text through javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4012387/custom-validator-error-text-through-javascript)

Comment: i used protected void cusCustom_ServerValidate1(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs e)
{
   it display's error message but it also allows Gridview to populate,while it should not be..
    if (lengthofbatch == 2)
    {
        e.IsValid = true;
    }
    else
    {
        e.IsValid = false;
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

That is server side validation @user2053138, you mentioned in comment.

Check out the following example:

```
<asp:TextBox id="Text1" 
       runat="server" />

  &nbsp;&nbsp;

  <asp:CustomValidator id="CustomValidator1"
       ControlToValidate="Text1"
       ClientValidationFunction="ClientValidate"
       OnServerValidate="ServerValidation"
       Display="Static"
       ErrorMessage="Not an even number!"
       ForeColor="green"
       Font-Name="verdana" 
       Font-Size="10pt"
       runat="server"/>

<script language="javascript"> 
  function ClientValidate(source, arguments)
  {
    if (arguments.Value % 2 == 0 ){
        arguments.IsValid = true;
    } else {
        arguments.IsValid = false;
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: :-but even no of attendance constraint should only fire when Dropdownlist named batch name should have value of length 2,it should not fire when  Dropdownlist named batch name should have value of length 1..Currently it is firing on both type of batch names..Plz help