# asp.net validation controls client script

Tags: asp.net

environment: asp.net 3.5

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="cvServerValidateDate" runat="server" 
    ControlToValidate="tbDate" onservervalidate="cvValidateServer" 
    ValidateEmptyText="True" ClientValidationFunction="validateDate"></asp:CustomValidator>



<script type="text/javascript">
    function validateDate(oSrc, args)
    {
        args.IsValid = (args.Value.length >= 8);        
    }
</script>
```

if the client-side validation is args.IsValid = false is there a way to access the validator's error message value to indicate a specific error? i have several different error messages and i'd like to send of them based on type of error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
oSrc.errormessage = "Your validation message here";
```

**Edit**

After some further digging I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230281/how-can-i-rewrite-the-errormessage-for-a-customvalidator-control-on-the-client) which has more detailed answer.